# Memory high using SSAS tabular

Tags: sql, ssas

I am using SSAS Tabular and the size of database is not big, and also users not much using ssas.

But my memory used is 98%. My memory already 64G.

Can you give me tips to reduce the memory ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this [post](http://www.powerpivotblog.com/what-is-using-all-that-memory-on-my-analysis-server-instance/) from Kasper Dejonge. 
Basically he gives you an excel spreadsheet with powerpivot. You connect it to your SSAS instance and it will show you the memory used by table/column. With it, We've reduced memory use and process time.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean by "my memory" the memory of your developer machine. SSAS Tabular loads all the Data in the Memory. To avoid this, we open the model.bim file in any Text Editor and search and replace all the "SELECT " commands by "SELECT TOP 1 PERCENT". This approach only loads 1 percent of the data in the Memory. After designing the cube structure we save the *.bim file and search and replace "SELECT TOP 1" by "SELECT TOP 100" and process the cube.

Comment: thats a Nice Trick 